# "Connection Reset" Error on accessing IIS 8.5 Server Site

Tags: iis, iis-8, connection-reset

I have create a very simple site in IIS Server version 8.5 using port 85. The site only have one index.html that shows the word "test" the page. When I access the site inside the server I can access it successfully: "http://localhost:85" is working.

**Trial 1:**
I try accessing it from my computer that is connected to the same network with the server using url "http://servername.test.com:85", the browser goes loading for long time and finally ends in with error "Connection Reset".

**Trial 2:** I try updating the Site Binding's Host name with our "Vanity Name" and "IP Address", but after this I still get a "Connection Reset" error.

[image]

**Trial 3:** Now I also check for opened ports using netstat, and I can see that port 85 is open. So I don't know why I'm getting Connection Reset error

[image]

**Trial 4:** I added Connection timeout value on the settings. But still I'm getting Connection Reset error.

[image]

Please kindly help with advise how to fix this Connection Reset issue. I can't find what is the reason behind this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Site bindings are key concepts you must learn first, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background Secondly, learn Windows Firewall.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for your answer about Windows Firewall where I had explored it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution. I issue was caused by Firewall enabled on the server and the ports are not opened by the Network Administrators. So I just opened the Ports that I will be using and it works now. Installing IIS Failure Tracing help me catch the error also. Thank you for all those who answered.

Answer (score 3):

According to your description, I guess you may not bind the right IP address for the  `servername.test.com` domain or use the wrong ip address bind with `servername.test.com` domain.

I suggest you could firstly try to use the server's ip address to access your web application to make sure you firewall setting and IP setting is right.

If your client server and the IIS server are in the same domain and you have installed an  DNS server, then you could access the web site by domain. Details about how to set the DNS server, you could refer to this [article](https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/11019-set-up-configure-dns-on-windows-server-2016.html).

If you just want to test, you could try to modify the hosts file in the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`  path in your client server.

For example:

```
127.0.0.1   www.example.com
```

Comment: This worked for me. hosts file was referring to 127.0.0.1, yet the IIS binding was configured to a different static IP